# Expokit SHA1 Signing certificate

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo

I've created an React Native app with Expo and ejected to Expokit. 
After adding React Native Firebase to the project, I need to generate a `SHA1 Certificate Fingerprints` to use phone authentication.

I tried generating the key with the below command, added it to firebase.

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore debug.keystore -list -v
```

Attempting to login (on physical device) returns an error.

[image]

I understand `Expo` manages keystores in default Expo apps, but am very confused with how to get these keys for my detached Expokit project.

How can I get the correct debug `SHA1 Fingerprint Certificates` Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, use Android Studio by adding that project in your android studio and you can easily get SHA1 fingerprint there!

```
Step:1 Go to Gradle.
Step 2: Select project root.
Step 3: Then select tasks.
Step 4: Then select android.
Step 5: Then click Signing report.
```